# Android: pass a resource id as a parameter

Tags: android, android-resources

I have this code:

```
translateRight("iv1"); //iv1 is an id of an imageView

    private void translateRight(String st){

    ImageView img = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.st);
        Animation a = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.translate_right);
        img.startAnimation(a);
    }
```

I have "translateRight" that is a method that show an animation, but at this method I should pass a resource id; I tried with a string but it don't work, what can I do?

Comment: By the way - it's more convinient to pass `ImageView` itself.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Resource id - is an integer value. Just pass an `int`:

```
private void translateRight(int resource){
    ImageView img = (ImageView) findViewById(resource);
    //stuff
}
```

Comment: Just adding on to this answer, the function accepts any integer value right now. So, if you pass -13 or some arbitrary number, it will accept it and will try to find a view with that id. This can be handled by adding `@IdRes` annotation in the parameter. This will ensure that only a `R.id` type int is sent at compile time.

Answer (score 5):

Resource ID is an integer, not a String.

Answer (score 1):

2. The second approach is that you directly pass the findViewById

   boolean tvStatus=status((CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.vn));

   ```
     public boolean status(CheckBox ch)
        {

            boolean ll=ch.isChecked() ;
            return  ll;
        }
   ```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please do not post another answer if you want to update your existing answer, use the [edit] button instead.

Answer (score 0):

I think there might be 2 approaches to do this.

1. passing id name in the method.

Here status is the method and id_name is the name of your id (It can be anything)

How you will receive this?

```
 // This is how you call the method
 status(R.id.id_name)

 public boolean status(int id)
    {
      CheckBox ch = findViewById(id);
      boolean = ch.isChecked();
      return s;
    }
```

Hope if it Helps...